# How would I add an autorole with Membership Screening Support?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to set up a brand new Discord Bot using discord.js v13. I am trying to get the Autorole function to work with Discord's Membership Screening, so when someone passes the Screening, they automatically get my "Standard User" role. But when someone passes the Membership Screening, the bot doesn't assign the role. I don't even get an error message. The Bot Has Proper Permissions, and is at the highest of the Role List as it can get.

This is That Main File where all the events are currently happening.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../config/config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandDirectories = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cmd'), { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter(dirent => dirent.isDirectory())
    .map(dirent => dirent.name);

for (const directory of commandDirectories) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cmd', directory)).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(path.join(__dirname, 'cmd', directory, file));
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('UpstartBot is Up');
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));
    if (!command) return;

    try {
        command.execute(message, args, Discord);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log(`${member.user.tag} has joined the server!`);

    const screeningRole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Standard User');
    const noRole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'No Access');
    const hasScreeningRole = member.roles.cache.has(screeningRole.id);
    const hasNoRole = member.roles.cache.has(noRole.id);
        // ! means true? no ! means false?
    if (hasScreeningRole) {
        const screeningCompleted = !member.pending;
        if (screeningCompleted) {
            member.roles.add(screeningRole)
            .then(console.log(`${member.user.tag} has been assigned the Standard User role`))
            .catch(console.error);
        }
    } else if (hasNoRole) {
        const screeningNotCompleted = member.pending;
        if (screeningNotCompleted) {
            member.roles.add(noRole)
            .then(console.log(`${member.user.tag} has been assigned the No Access role`))
            .catch(console.error);
        }
    }
});


client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Where exactly is the screening and the role giving part in your code?

Comment: Hey, i just updated the code. its under guildMemberAdd

Comment: Are both `hasScreeningRole` and `hasNoRole` false? If not then, what does `member.pending` return?

Comment: Hey, i figured it out...I had to use guildMemberUpdate instead of guildMemberAdd